# COALESCE for no rows returned

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I am using COALESCE to return first non-null values. In below query I am trying to get data for that day of the week which has latest data / or some data (Starting Sunday - Monday). So Let's say if Sunday, Tuesday, Monday has data it should return me Sunday data. If all days have data , it should return me Sunday (7) data. But below query does not return anything. May be because the value returned is zero rows instead of null ??

```
 SELECT *
        FROM
    status_summary
    WHERE COALESCE(("day_of_week"(Datetime) = 7),("day_of_week"(Datetime) = 6),
    ("day_of_week"(Datetime) = 5),("day_of_week"(Datetime) = 4),
    ("day_of_week"(Datetime) = 3),("day_of_week"(Datetime) = 2),
    ("day_of_week"(Datetime) = 1))
```

When i run individual query like below, it returns me data.

```
SELECT *
            FROM
        status_summary
        WHERE COALESCE(("day_of_week"(Datetime) = 5))
```

OR

```
   SELECT *
                FROM
            status_summary
            WHERE COALESCE(("day_of_week"(Datetime) = 4))
```

The syntax is in presto (AWS Athena) but I don't mind sql syntax as well.

```
SQL : datename(day,MyDate) = 'Sunday'
```

Comment: COALESCE checks for null condition in the data per row.  if null then it uses the alternate parameter coalese(variable1, variable2).  if not null use varable1 other variable2

Comment: How to use variable in above use case ?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying you want to show every row with a date of Sunday and, if there are none, then show every row with a date of Saturday, etc?

Comment: Coalesce is a one or the other case when or else condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have the sub-select pick the day of week, something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM status_summary
WHERE day_of_week(Datetime) = (SELECT MAX(day_of_week(Datetime)) FROM status_summary)
```

Comment: is their a way to customize this query and check for every year -> every month -> every week -> Get me the latest record of that week available ? Currently the problem with above query is if there is data for 17th Nov 2021 and 12th Dec 2021 , it only picks 12th Dec rather i want to pick it for  every year -> every month -> every week -> Get me the latest record of that week

Comment: I don't quite understand your requirement, but if you want the 'latest', then you could use: `ORDER BY Datetime DESC LIMIT 1`  That will sort by the Date (Descending) and will just return the first row.